# How to fix loss of session in http calls from angular 7 to Jersey service

Tags: angular, session, jersey

I make HTTP calls from angular 7 client to Jersey REST service using Tomcat. The problem is that the session is lost after login.

I tried using different headers, but got no solution.
I don't use a proxy.
I use a CORS filter and a login+session filter that shows me that the session is lost after sucessful login. The session filter is only used afer login, in subsequent HTTP calls. I tested the service using POSTMAN and session is not lost in this case.

Angular call to HTTP login service:

```
public login(user: User): Observable<number> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponsWebApp/user/login';
    return this.httpService.post<number>(url, user, {withCredentials: true})
.pipe(catchError(this.messageService.handleError<number>('login'))
    );
}
```

CORSFilter in server:

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");

res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Content-Type");
```

Login and session filter in server:

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
System.out.println("session=" + session);
if (session == null) { // session expired
    try {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath() + "/user/login");
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
    CouponClientFacade couponClientFacade = (CouponClientFacade) session.getAttribute("CouponClientFacade");
    System.out.println("couponClientFacade=" + couponClientFacade);
if (couponClientFacade == null) { // not logged in
    try {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath() + "/user/login");
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

I expected to get the session in session filter, but it prints session=null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to add some parameters in Chrome, useful for dev environment only:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:\temp-chrome"

Answer (score 0):

you should add `{withCredentials: true}` to all of the request, not just login. it forces http requests to send cookies with it, and, as a result, session could be retrieved

Comment: I use `{withCredentials: true}`in all of my requests, but it doesnt help.